# Google +1 for questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I see how Google +1 changes my search results and of my friends as it pushes those links ahead in the search results which I and my friends have +1ed.

I see Twitter, FB options for sqa question but no Google +1. I think we should have +1 on site. What do you say?

n.b. I am not really really sure if it right forum to post this question.

Comment: Yes, it's a no brainer in my opinion.

Comment: This is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

[This was requested on Meta.SO as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future). The current answer is "not *yet*":

> As Arjan noted, we're not inclined to support this until Google+ produces a standard, simple hyperlink way of sharing, the same as our current Twitter and Facebook sharing links. We don't want to slow down every page with third party requests and weird  techniques.
>
> There is no such method at this time, but I have been in contact with Google about this matter, and they are aware of our request.